# how to add strings that are in the same parameter

Tags: javascript, html, string, parameters

I would like to add two strings together, so that if `7` and `8` are clicked, the function sets `outputbox`'s inner HTML to `78`. However, with this current function, it only shows the number most recently selected. How can I get it to show every number that's been selected?

```javascript
function selectNum(num)
{
    num = num + num // What goes here?
    document.getElementById("outputbox").innerHTML = num;
}
```

```html
<button onclick = "selectNum('7')">7</button>
<button onclick = "selectNum('8')">8</button>
<button onclick = "selectNum('9')">9</button>
<button onclick = "selectNum('4')">4</button>
<button onclick = "selectNum('5')">5</button>
<button onclick = "selectNum('6')">6</button>
<button onclick = "selectNum('1')">1</button>
<button onclick = "selectNum('2')">2</button>
<button onclick = "selectNum('3')">3</button>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
var number = '';
function selectNum(num) {
    number += num;
    document.getElementById("outputbox").innerHTML = number;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The trivial answer is to just concatenate the number to the current value of the element:

```
function selectNum(num) {
  document.getElementById("outputbox").innerHTML += num;
}
```

However, a more robust method is to store the value separately and write it to the document. A global variable can be avoided by using an immediately invoked function expression and keeping the value in a closure:

```
var selectNum = (function() {
  var value = '';
  return function (num) {
    value += num;
    document.getElementById("outputbox").innerHTML = value;
  };
}());
```

You might want to include a way to clear or reset the value.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a variable outside the scope of "selectNum" and use closure to let the function modify it.

```
var myString = "";
function selectNum(num) {
    myString += num;

    document.getElementById("outputbox").innerHTML = myString;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A cleaner approach avoiding the deprecated use of inline javascript, while using event listeners and a reset button. [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/clarketm/xrmeaunm/3/)

**HTML:**

```
<div>
    <button class="sumBtn">1</button>
    <button class="sumBtn">2</button>
    <button class="sumBtn">3</button>
    <button class="sumBtn">4</button>
    <button class="sumBtn">5</button>
    <button class="sumBtn">6</button>
    <button class="sumBtn">7</button>
    <button class="sumBtn">8</button>
    <button class="sumBtn">9</button>
    <button id="resetBtn">Reset</button>
</div>
```

**Javascript:**

```
var sumButtons = document.getElementsByClassName('sumBtn');
var resetBtn = document.getElementById('resetBtn');
var total = "";

function reset() {
    total = '';
    // alert(total);
}

function addNums(num) {
    total += num;
    // alert(total);
}

for (var i = 0; i < sumButtons.length; i++) {
    sumButtons[i].addEventListener('click', function () {
        addNums(this.textContent);
    });
}

resetBtn.addEventListener('click', function () {
    reset();
});
```

**UPDATE:** removed the console alert and replaced it with an input box to display the result. [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/clarketm/xrmeaunm/4/)

Comment: One small thing: You didn't set the `id` of the reset button to `reset`; you need to change the HTML to `<button id="reset">` to have that. I'd also like to point out that, while this is good for demo code, you should add a class of some sort (e.g. `<button class="form_buttom">`) and use `document.getElementsByClassName('form_button')` so that you can use more `button` tags than just those in this form, as well as not including the reset button in your list.

Comment: @QPaysTaxes Good point. I'll "clean" it up with classes for cross-application usability.